# Wordpress 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, wordpress

my demo WordPress site hosted in www.domain.com/test folder, after theme modification I moved this site to www.domain.com unfortunately, site's shows **500 Internal Server Error**

I edited option in **option_value**(database) and rearrange to www.domain.com/

Comment: One of the reason I know is permission is not given to that theme folder.

Comment: You'll usually have to do more than update the options table - there will be numerous references to the old URL (eg images in posts).  Have a look at the [Moving WordPress codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).  Having said that, I'm not sure why you'd get a 500 error.  Any detail in your PHP logs?

Comment: I normally use [Search / Replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) for moving a Wordpress to another domain. You can use regex to make sure you get both with www and without. If you don't want this on your live site, just grab the SQL, host it locally then simply search & replace!

Comment: The changes you made caused an error. You haven't told us anything about the error nor about the changes, so it's impossible for anyone to give a better answer than that. Check your web server's error logs to find out more about the error. Revert the changes to stop the error from occurring. Test them for syntax errors before uploading them next time.

Comment: [This is the best way](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#If_You_Have_Accidentally_Changed_your_WordPress_Site_URL) to move wordpress to another domain